# Publish Office js Addin to local folder and load it in Excel Desktop App

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

I am building an Excel Addin using Excel JS Api. My client wishes to run the Addin completely off-line, meaning that no internet connection will be available.

As a part of this requirement, I wish to Publish the Addin to a local Folder. I am doing it through Visual Studio. Once Publish Process is over I am getting the published files & folders and a destination like this : **"file///C:Users/User10/MyExcelAddin"**

Is it possible to update manifest source location to the previous destination and load the addin with this configuration from a Trusted Addin catalogue to the Excel Desktop App?

[image]

I tried but it fails even to detect the manifest. But once I run the Addin through VS with the previous configuration it works.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, An Add-in that uses the Office JS APIs is a web application, based on the current design, it requires to be hosted on a web server or in a cloud-based web application hosting service. So Excel Web Add-in cannot run offline currently.

But I would suggest you to vote this request at UserVoice https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/36034516-make-possible-to-install-office-add-ins-permanentl